# Can I Move RAID-1 (Mirrored) Hard Drives From a Hardware Raid Controller to Software Raid?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid1

Old server:

- 3ware 9650se PCIe hardware RAID controller with 2 sets of RAID-1 (4 total drives, 2 mirrored) with a 5th drive as a hot-spare.

New server:

- Software RAID is the only option.  Plan to run linux `mdadm` with the same RAID-1 configurations.

These are not boot drives, storing just data.

Can I transfer the drives from hardware RAID to software RAID?  Will the data be intact?

Answer (score 3):

Linux Software RAID (`md`) has a support for some of hardware RAIDs superblocks, `man mdadm`:

```
-e ddf    Use  the  "Industry Standard" DDF (Disk Data Format) format defined by SNIA.
```

If 3ware's metadata format is not supported when you plug the disks into usual SATA ports all data they have should be accessible to the system.

Since it's RAID-1 you aren't at a huge risk when trying but the real safe side is having backups first anyways.

A few different RAID-1 "jumpstart procedures" can be applied:

1. you create an `md` device using a single disk and `empty` another — that would give you LSR superblock applied then you could just add the second disk onto "empty" slot.
2. Or, you could start basically with both disks at once using `--assume-clean` when creating it.

Middle risk approach is using 3 disks for this procedure — if you have a 3rd blank one just use it for procedure 1 adding second disk. That way you always have a full copy of your data on second replica of HW RAID array which isn't touched by any operation.

Comment: Good info! Do you know of downsides to using `-e ddf` as in negative performance or reliability?

Comment: Nah, it's not that common.

Answer (score -2):

No, you would have to transfer/copy/backup data from your HW RAID volume and then move it to your software RAID volume.

Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46381/migrating-from-hardware-to-software-raid